# System notification message in message center

Tags: mac

I think this is a virus but I'm not sure. I cannot seem to find an answer online on how to make it stop. I have checked under safari and preferences and under system preferences.[image]

Answer (score -1):

"NOTIFICATION SYSTEM" is not a system notification, or not one I've ever seen.

The header is the 'app' generating the notification. In this case, as the icon looks like Safari then it could be some site you allowed to send you notifications.
(As I tend to have most of these switched off, I'm not certain if the wording they use in that header is Safari's or the remote site's responsibility.)

Safari > Preferences > Websites > Notifications

[image]

Check which sites you wish to allow to be able to do that - mostly you can switch them off, allow only the ones you really need, otherwise it's a spam-fest

Comment: Thanks but I have already don't that. I do not have any websites trying to send me a notification, that page is completely empty.